# How can create divs on option change?

Tags: jquery

I want to create divs with the class name `colors` by option `.on("change")`. It works well, but anytime I change the option, more and more `div`'s are created. But I have only two `colors`, so as a result anytime I change the option, I only want to see two divs: "blue" and "red". I tried to used `$('.result').remove();` before appending. But then nothing is appended.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select").on("change", function() {
    $(".colors").each(function() {
      var color = $(this).attr('title');
      $(".result").append("<div>" + color + "</div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option class="colors" title="blue">a</option>
  <option class="colors" title="red">b</option>
  <option title="green">c</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do what you require you can simply call `empty()` on the `.result` div before you loop through and create the new div elements. Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select").on("change", function() {
    $('.result').empty();
    
    $(".colors").each(function() {
      $(".result").append("<div>" + this.title + "</div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option class="colors" title="blue">a</option>
  <option class="colors" title="red">b</option>
  <option title="green">c</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Comment: Just answered the same thing, my boss called me, 5 mins gone and you took over! :D

Answer (score 3):

You are not clearing your `.result` and appending more elements. You can use `html('')` to clear the result.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("#select").on("change", function() {
   $('.result').html('');
  $( ".colors" ).each(function() {
     var product = $(this).attr('title');
    $(".result").append("<div>" + product + "</div>"); 
});   
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<select id="select">
  <option class="colors" title="blue">a</option>
  <option class="colors" title="red">b</option>
  <option title="green">c</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```

Also, you should not use `.remove()` to clear html contents. `.remove()` removes the element completely. Click [link](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) to know about `.remove()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove html of the div like  $('.result').html('');

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#select").on("change", function() {
    $('.result').html('');
    
    $(".colors").each(function() {
      var color = $(this).attr('title');
      $(".result").append("<div>" + color + "</div>");
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="select">
  <option class="colors" title="blue">a</option>
  <option class="colors" title="red">b</option>
  <option title="green">c</option>
</select>

<div class="result"></div>
```